# why I cannot find my website in google search when search in Arabic language?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I cannot find my website when search in google and using Arabic language .

In English language I can find the site direct but the issue in Arabic language not appear .

I tried this code in my main layout and used meta and title as all sites recommended :

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>مختبرات القمة الطبية</title>
    <meta name="description" content="مختبرات القمة الطبية ترحب بكم وتقدم لكم افضل الخدمات وافضل كادر طبي واحدث اجهزة التحاليل الطبية في مدينة الطائف " />
    <meta name="keywords" content="alqemah,alqemahlab,alqemah laboratory,laboratory,القمه,مختبر القمه ,مختبر القمة الطائف ,مختبر القمة,مختبرات طبية,مختبرات القمة الطبية"/>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
    
  
</head>
```

what I need to do to find website when search in Arabic language in google

your kind help please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not seeing the appropriate tags for telling Google about your site languages.
You need to use `x-default` for the default language and you need to add multiple `hreflang` links to specify alternate version of your pages, in each page. You could also achieve this by using `hreflang` in your sitemap.

Have a look at Google's documentation: [Managing multi-regional and multilingual sites](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/managing-multi-regional-sites#top_of_page).

Comment: my site only english language my issue when search in google and search by " مختبرات القمة الطبية " its not showing the site but when I added the title and I need to find the website when search by the title in Arabic language , can you give example about x-default and hreflang ?